# If a Django app only works with Gunicorn's `--preload` option, does it mean that there is something wrong with the app?

Tags: django, gunicorn

Inherited an outdated Django app (Django 2.2) running in "production", served by Gunicorn without the `--preload` option. New to Python and the Django ecosystem, but was able to update everything to latest (Django 4.2, Gunicorn 20.1.0) without ever having to touch the codebase (apart from `settings.py`, but even there the changes were minimal).

`django manage.py runserver` works, so tried Gunicorn next. The app gets served, and when I try to log in, the credentials are accepted, but then redirected to the login page. The next attempts load some of the initial page that a user should see after signing in, but it is mixed with the login form somehow. `--log-level 'debug'` shows no issues, no errors from the app (at least what I could find).

`--preload` solves this issue right away, and now I know that this option is ok to be used in production. Nonetheless, given my inexperience, I wonder if this is normal or something that I should definitely address once moving to actually working on the app itself.

---

Decided to post this here and not on Unix & Linux, ServerFault, or SuperUser, because even though the question involves Gunicorn and its terminal usage, it is about Django really.